# How to fix Unprotected Private Key file on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, terminal

I am trying to add my ssh private key file to a Mac in the terminal. When I run:

```
ssh-add -k / /path/file
```

this is the error I'm getting:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for '/Volumes/CREATIF IV/Creatif IV/Creatif IV_web/Personal/ssh-keys/anker/anker-prv_key.ppk' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, private keys should only be manageable by the owner, optionally for the group (for example, if it has to be managed by `apache2`, it can be readable by the `ssl-cert` group) and have no permissions for the group and the others. So:

```
chmod 600 "/Volumes/CREATIF IV/Creatif IV/Creatif IV_web/Personal/ssh-keys/anker/anker-prv_key.ppk"
```

Should be enough in this case.

Comment: still same error. Should i get some sort of response after this command is entered?

Comment: No, it just returns nothing, which is the successful result. Try listing the file with `ls` and paste the current result.

Comment: No worries man, my mistake. Your right, the fact that i didn't return anything means it was successful. Also my spacing between 600 and the file path was an issue... #trueNoob

Comment: also i moved the file from my drive to the desktop

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should assign the right permission for the file (`chmod 600 file`), but since it's on your external drive which could not support permissions, try adding it from the standard input to bypass the permission checks, for example:

```
cat "/Volumes/path/prv_key.ppk" | ssh-add -k/ -
```